# PHP loses field datatype for MySQL results (everything becomes string)

Tags: php, mysql, json, types

The following code shows that fields like datetime, float and decimal in my test table, all come back as string in PHP.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($row);
```

Why does PHP not recognize and use the proper datatype for the field from the MySQL database?

My testsystem is running Mac OS X with PHP 5.3.2 and MySQL 5.1.44.
I generally have UTF8 encoded data, and tried both the InnoDB and MyISAM database types.

Comment: How does the output look like? And what does this have to do with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_* doesn't know about datatypes. I believe if you use mysqli it will recognize some datatypes.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not intrinsically deal with MySQL DATETIME fields in any way other than as a string. You need to look at the php date() function to format it in a way that suits your needs.

Comment: You can also translate `DATETIME` to a unix timestamp by either querying for it from the SQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATETIMEFIELD)` or using `strtotime` in php